# SVN Include new file in project

Tags: vb.net, svn

I added a new VB class in a new page to my local Visual Studio project and everything worked fine.  I checked that new page into our SVN repository, but when the next person does a checkout they get my page, but it's not part of the project.  They have to right click on it and include it.  If I add that page and then also commit my project file, the next download would get my file and it would be included.

But what if someone else also had a new page/class to add, they'll commit their page and their project, but now my page is dropped out of the project again (we don't do continuous updating by any stretch) and if I commit mine back in, theirs drops out.

So I'd have to upload my new file and new project and then everyone else will have to do a SVN Update to get a new project file and then they continue on their way.

Is there a way to add a new file to SVN and have it included in the project?

Comment: Commit the page and the project (make sure you save the project!). And it should force them to update before they commit, which would merge your changes into theirs, right?

Comment: Typically you want to keep project files out of version control, for exactly this reason. That's something the build system should take care of.

Comment: If I right click on the project and commit in VS, it adds every single file that's different from the repository so we'd have to be super careful what was checked off when you commit the update.  If I update the .vbproj file through the file system it only uploads that specific file but it means I have to remember to commit via the file system for new additions.  We're in the middle of a release right now so I won't be able to test fully until that's complete but I'll try later this week.

Comment: @Dave The .vbproj file is what specifies what's in the project, so you really must commit it to SVN any time you add or remove files to/from the project. In my experience, best practice is to do a commit from the root of your working copy (which may be the solution level or a bit higher, depending on how your code is organized) and de-select anything that you know isn't ready, provided you don't break the compile by doing so.